# How to find cumulative sum of specific column in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file in the format:

```
20 05 2019 12:00:00, 100

21 05 2019 12:00:00, 200

22 05 2019 12:00:00, 480
```

And i want to access the second variable, ive tried a variety of different alterations but none have worked.
Initially i tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col = [i for i in range(2)]
col[1] = "Power"
data = pd.read_csv('FILENAME.csv', names=col)


df1 = data.sum(data, axis=1)
df2 = np.cumsum(df1)
print(df2)
```

Comment: What is the expected answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` function:

```
data['Power'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    100
1    300
2    780
Name: Power, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`df.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):**

```
In [1820]: df = pd.read_csv('FILENAME.csv', names=col)    
In [1821]: df
Out[1821]: 
                     0  Power
0  20 05 2019 12:00:00    100
1  21 05 2019 12:00:00    200
2  22 05 2019 12:00:00    480

In [1823]: df['cumulative sum'] = df['Power'].cumsum()    
In [1824]: df    
Out[1824]: 
                     0  Power  cumulative sum
0  20 05 2019 12:00:00    100             100
1  21 05 2019 12:00:00    200             300
2  22 05 2019 12:00:00    480             780
```